# python, remove words in a string from a list

Tags: python, string, list

I want to remove words in a string, which the words or 'seed' words in a list,

example:

```
query = "LK936033.1 Babesia assembly 454hybrid_PBjelly scaffold Contig1323  7"
seeds = ["assembly","454","scaffold","contig"]
```

expect result:

```
"LK936033.1 Babesia 7"
```

I found a way to do remove words like this:

```
' '.join([i for i in query.split() if i not in seeds])
```

but this method only removes the *exact* words from the seed list, but not the words containing the seeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to expand your test; use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) for efficiency:

```
' '.join([i for i in query.split() if not any(w in i.lower() for w in seeds)])
```

The `any(w in i.lower() for w in seeds)` test uses a generator expression to test if the current word contains any of the seed words, lowercased; it'll only evaluate the minimum number of tests to find a match.

Demo:

```
>>> query = "LK936033.1 Babesia assembly 454hybrid_PBjelly scaffold Contig1323  7"
>>> seeds = ["assembly","454","scaffold","contig"]
>>> ' '.join([i for i in query.split() if not any(w in i.lower() for w in seeds)])
'LK936033.1 Babesia 7'
```